# SPOJ 91 (Two squares or not two squares) optimization in Python

Tags: python, optimization

Im trying to practice python by attempting SPOJ problems and im kinda stuck on the [91st problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TWOSQRS/)

Ive used [Fermat's Theorem for sum of 2 squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) for the logic of the program, but i keep getting the 'Time Limit Exceeded' error when testing the solution.
Heres the code:

```
import sys import math

def factor(n):
    d=2
    primfac = []

    while d*d <= n:
        while n%d == 0:
            primfac.append(d)
            n/=d
        d+=1
    return primfac

def fun(num):
    factors = factor(num)
    r=0
    prevr = 0
    inc=1

    if factors == [] and num%4==1:
        return 1

    for f in factors:
        if f%2!=0 and f%4==3:
            r=f
            if r==prevr:
                inc+=1
            prevr = f

    if inc%2==0:
        return 1

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=0
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if(x==0):
            x=1
            continue

        n = int(line)

        if(fun(n) == 1):
            print 'Yes'
        else:
            print 'No'
```

Im guessing there might be some optimizations and small tweaks i can add to make the code run faster, but im clueless what they are.. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code, when submitted (Python 2.7), yields *wrong answer*, not *Time Limit Exceeded*. For input value 2 it incorrectly prints 'No'.